# Change center img to smaller ones on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

need help with code i need a big img in the center and a row of 6 smaller ones. Here is what I did so far i cant get it to change for some reason ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment 5</title>
</head>
<body onload="conv()">
<img id="img1" style="height:1000px;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globemain.jpg"         alt="taiwan">
<img onmouseover="new()" style="height:100;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globemain.jpg" alt="taiwan">
<img onmouseover="new()" style="height:100;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globe2.jpg" alt="car">
<img onmouseover="new()" style="height:100;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globe3.jpg" alt="globeC">
<img onmouseover="new()" style="height:100;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globe4.jpg" alt="globeD">
<img onmouseover="new()" style="height:100;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globe5.jpg" alt="globeE">
<img onmouseover="new()" style="height:100;" src="http://www.albany.edu/~ds857942/Images/globe6.jpg" alt="globeF">

<script>
function conv() {
var a = document.getElementById("img1");
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
a.style.height=0.6* screen.availHeight + "px";
a.style.height= 0.6* screen.availWidth + "px";

for (var x = 1;x<=6;x++) {
b[x].style.height=0.15* screen.availHeight + "px";
b[x].style.height=0.15* screen.availwidth + "px";
}
}
function new(img1){
document.getElementById("img1").src = eval( img1 + b[x].src );  
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "New" is a keyword in JS

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 transitions would work perfectly for this. Simply do something like this in your CSS:

```
body > img {
    height:100px;
    transition:height .5s;
}
body > img:hover {
    height:50px;
}
```

It seems you do not currently have a CSS file so I advise you make one or add your styles to the head tag inside **style** tags.